# iOS Distribution "Unable to process application Info.plist"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Currently I try to submit an iOS 7 app to app store using XCode 5.0

The app is already in app store - I did some fixed for iOS 7 and want to submit the binary now.

The message I get is
"Unable to process application Info.plist validation at this time due to a general error. Please try again later".

First I thought it would be a problem at Apples servers. Since the problem consists for 2 days now, I started to look for others with similar problems.
Some managed to fix the problem by using different app icons - but the topics I found was some month old.

However, my problem still exists.

I provided all icons in all possible formats (57x57, 72x72, 114x114, 144x144, 120x120), but still no success.

Currently I really hate apple for making life that complicated.

Maybe someone have an idea ?

Here is my Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>Germany</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>myAppName</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon120x120</string>
        <string>Icon.png</string>
        <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>de.xxx.xxx</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.7</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.7</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv6</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

XCode 5 DP does not allow submit apps to App Store.

You should wait for official XCode 5.0 release.

Comment: ok, thanks for that information....and thanks to apple that my users won't be able to use my app several days after the iOS7 release due to approval times

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove armv6 from Architectures in Build Settings, everything will be alright.
I also got this trouble for 2 weeks...

Reference : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5546617

Answer (score 0):

For me it was CFBundleIconFiles key in Info.plist that was causing the issue with validation. Simply removed it and it worked.